# Адрес какой памяти мы получаем в Си при использовании &?

Tags: c, память

Допустим, у нас есть `int t = 2;`.
Когда мы выводим `&t`, это адрес в виртуальной памяти или физической?

И еще: почему адреса переменных при каждом запуске программы разные?

Comment: В языке С нет никакой "виртуальной" или "физической" памяти. Есть просто *память*. А то, что адреса у вас почему-то получились каждый раз разные - ну что? Никто вам никогда не обещал, что они будут одинаковыми "при каждом запуске". Все остальное - детали реализации, которую вы почему-то в своем вопросе даже не упомянули. Откуда же нам знать, что там у вас происходит?

Comment: Память бывает виртуальная и физическая. Физическая - это вся RAM. Виртуальная - это память программы. Виртуальные адреса отображаются на физические. Вот я и хочу узнать, амперсанд возвращает виртуальный адрес или физический?

Comment: Это у вас в компьютере и в вашей ОС, по-видимому, такое бывает (в каких-то бывает, в каких-то - не бывает). Языку С это никак не видно и не известно, языку С этого нет никакого дела и оператору `&` тоже. На практике, если вы работаете на традиционной платформе с виртуальной памятью, то разумеется `&` будет адресом в виртуальной памяти. Доступа к адресам в RAM у вас нет и быть не может.

Comment: Да, если Вы работаете на винде или линуксе, то в отладчике скорее всего Вам показывают адрес виртуальной памяти. Потому, что физическая память обслуживается драйвером MMU и так просто к ней доступ не получишь. Что касается разного адреса переменной t от запуска к запуску, то этого быть не должно, если Вы конечно не вставили в код дополнительные строки, которые сдвинули адрес переменной t.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, на системах с [ASLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) различие адресов между запусками ­— норма жизни...